# What would be involved in creating a template system in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm creating a project in C# and I want to be able to define "template" files that define the layout that will be produced in an ASP web page. This means from an interface people are able to click certain "areas" and add text, images or a video.

I can only think of using the coordinates to achieve this. Any better ways? Any tips would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look at MasterPages in ASP.NET, it's exactly what you are looking for, content regions to be editable in pages associated with the main masterpage.

Comment: Can I edit this from within a desktop application? The ASP would be hosted on a server and there would be a connection from the client to the server.

Comment: mmm do you mean that you want to edit the content with the browser, like when editing a blog post or here in stackoverflow? sure you can but you must write logic for this and have somewhere a page with an HTML editor, if you want to create a blog or similar then there are tons of blog engines even for free that you could use.

Comment: No, I want to be able to edit it from a desktop client, which would then interact with the server to add the resources and add a new page with the users details.

Comment: I'm thinking that I may be able to have a master page and then have the ability to add resources and generate pages from the master page with the users added resources. I'll take a look at Master Pages a little more.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for user-editable templates? Then you want to look at Web Parts. (Web Parts are probably more often associated with SharePoint, but they do exist in ASP.NET without SharePoint.)

Comment: See the discussion above this answer. I'm looking to be able to add resources to a template and then generate a new web page. I'm thinking I may need to just store the information in SQL or flat-file and call it when loading the page.

Answer (score 1):

I'd pre-define a set of user controls to provide different layout and/or DB access options. I'd style them with CSS and steer clear of XSLT for this particular task.

You could then dynamically load these user controls into the content placeholders defined in master page(s). You don't need to implement Web Parts in order to add content - just create separate admin to add text/images to these areas.